# how fix script cache:clear returned error code 255 in symfony 4

Tags: php, xampp, symfony4

I get a project by command-line git clone on bitbucket.
I run `php ../composer.phar install` and I had after installing all these dependencies the following error:

> Executing script cache:clear [KO]  [KO] Script cache:clear returned
>   with error code 255 !! !!  Warning: require(... PHP Fatal error: 
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\aksymfony4\myProjetSf4\vendor\composer/../symfony/validator/Resources/functions/dump.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

[image]

How fix this error?

Thanks

**I use:**

Xampp v3.2.4,
Symfony 4.4,
php: 7.3.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try run the installation by administrator powershell.

And does those file exist or not, if not try install again,

or go to the dependency of github to download